# What was the significance of the Schleswig-Holstein question in the 19th century?

Tags: 19th-century, denmark, german-unification, imperial-germany

As the title states, what was the specific significance of the [Schleswig-Holstein question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schleswig%E2%80%93Holstein_question) (Denmark and the German Confederation arguing over contested lands) as it directly relates to German unification in 1871 and the concept of German identity that existed throughout the 19th and 20th centuries?

Comment: what is the Schleswig-Holstein question?

Comment: @LouisRhys It was a debate in the 19th century between Denmark and Prussia over what to do with the contested lands bordering the two nations.

Comment: This looks like the exact phrasing you'd see on a school assignment...

Answer (score 7):

Schleswig-Holstein became the rallying point for a united Germany, first in a war of Prussia and Austria against Denmark for the two provinces, then in a war of Prussia versus Austria. When Prussia won both times, it established itself as the dominant power in north Germany, around which the north German states coalesced. (Pulling in south Germany came later, after the victorious Franco-Prussian war.)

Comment: Actually, the southern German states were already "in" after 1866, via a system of military alliances (https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutz-_und_Trutzb%C3%BCndnisse_1866). Most north German states had already been on Prussia's side in the 1866 war.

Answer (score 1):

By supporting German states in their bid for independence from Denmark, Prussia was able to position itself as a champion of German nationalism, particularly in the question between a "small" Germany excluding Austria, and a "great" Germany including it.

Comment: This answer is true but only half true, because in the first stage Austria and Prussia were allies against Denmark. Fortunately, the other answer gets it right.